# PyQt error with json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a problem with the following code (I'm using Python 2.7 and PyQt4):

```
class Ui_login_dialog(object):
    def loginCheck(self):
        print("Login button clicked...")
        username = self.username_login.text()
        password = self.password_login.text()
        print("Your ID is:" + username + " and your password is " + password)
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/input").send_keys(username) #username
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/input").send_keys(password)  #password
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/span/button").click()  #click login button
```

everything works well until the last 3 lines (when it has to actually type the username and password).
What I would like to do is extract "username" and "password" from my login form created with PyQt designer and use them in selenium.

I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u't') is not JSON serializable
```

What can I do to solve this problem? Is there a way to easily convert that JSON in a "readable" format?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to call `str()` on it first.

Comment: Cool, glad it's working for you now. As an aside, please consider not making assumptions about my gender.